# How to stop Doctrine 2 from caching a result in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, caching, doctrine-orm, symfony

I want to be able to retrieve the existing version of an entity so I can compare it with the latest version. E.g. Editing a file, I want to know if the value has changed since being in the DB.

```
    $entityManager = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
    $postManager = $this->get('synth_knowledge_share.manager');

    $repository = $entityManager->getRepository('KnowledgeShareBundle:Post');
    $post = $repository->findOneById(1); 

    var_dump($post->getTitle()); // This would output "My Title"
    $post->setTitle("Unpersisted new title");

    $existingPost = $repository->findOneById(1); // Retrieve the old entity

    var_dump($existingPost->getTitle()); // This would output "Unpersisted new title" instead of the expected "My Title"
```

Does anyone know how I can get around this caching?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's a normal behavior.

Doctrine stores a reference of the retrieved entities in the EntityManager so it can return an entity by it's id without performing another query.

You can do something like :

```
$entityManager = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
$repository = $entityManager->getRepository('KnowledgeShareBundle:Post');
$post = $repository->find(1);

$entityManager->detach($post);

// as the previously loaded post was detached, it loads a new one
$existingPost = $repository->find(1);
```

But be aware of that as the $post entity was detached, you must use the ->merge() method if you want to persist it again.

Comment: Delicious, the 'detach' is perfect.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Quick tip - if you need to detach all entities (eg in non-insulated tests), you can use `$entityManager->clear()`.

Comment: The other thing to watch here is whether or not you have a transaction open.  If you've done an `$entityManager->beginTransaction()`, make sure you close the transaction (e.g. `$entityManager->rollback()`) before trying to clear the entity manager.  An open transaction will force a consistent, therefore not updated, view of the database.

Comment: For _most_ situations, for _most_ people, _most_ of the time, **refresh()** (see Battle Mage's answer) is probably the more natural solution.

Answer (score 23):

You can also use the `refresh` method, which refreshes the persistent state of an entity from the database, overriding any local changes that have not yet been persisted.
Something like:

```
$entityManager = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
$repository = $entityManager->getRepository('KnowledgeShareBundle:Post');
$post = $repository->find(1);

$entityManager->refresh($post);
```

now $post contains the last version from database.

Comment: You sir are a life saver!

Comment: this is really useful and seems to be little known.  Worth noting to have cascade="REFRESH" on related entities for this to work nicely