# Symfony2/Doctrine2 (MySQL) Updates not showing on a Select immediately after Update

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have several updates occurring in Doctrine2, each are inside a transaction.

At the end of this code is a Select query that returns a load of data using the [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle). But some of the updates are not present in the returned JSON from the JMSSerializerBundle.

I do not think its related to JMSSerializerBundle.

But more related to Doctrine2. If I run the select query again then the data is there. So it is there, its just not returned inside the same HTTP call.

The code is relatively simple so I have not included, this is more an issue around understanding what might be happening for updated data to be shown and some not.

The transaction should have finished by the time the select query occurs shouldn't it?

The order is as follows:

- start transaction
- make changes to entity
- persist
- flush
- commit

Comment: Have you persist()'ed the entities?

Comment: Yeah, just edited my Q for you.

Comment: Sorry I should rephrase; are you SURE you have persisted? :D I have done it loads of times where I modify but then completely forget to persist or persisted at the wrong point. Without a code sample its probably the firs thing to look at.

Comment: Yes. Because if I hadn't then it wouldn't work at all, even on subsequent requests?

Comment: It really depends how you are implementing it(I.e. I have found the most common areas I missed a persist are within loops). Again, without code its quite difficult to spot.

Comment: Not sure whether this is you case, but inside a single http call the later entity fetch might not be actually queried from the database but rather just returned from the entity manager directly if it is already fetched before... if you want to guarantee to get the latest database version you can use entity manager detach / clear functions. There is some more explanation here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956027/how-to-stop-doctrine-2-from-caching-a-result-in-symfony-2)

Comment: I guess this is similar to `$em->refresh($entity)` too? Although finding the docs on these functions is next to impossible! The search on the doctrine2 site docs is broken :-( Any ideas?

Comment: @ejuhjav that was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It may depend on the **isolation level** in the transaction. 
To make it work inside the transaction, you need to set this:

```
$entityManager
    ->getConnection()
    ->setTransactionIsolation(Connection::TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
```

In this way, anything written in the transaction is also readable.

Other possible values:

```
const TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED = 1;
const TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED = 2;
const TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ = 3;
const TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE = 4;
```