# Force doctrine to always refresh

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've got a script that fetches data from a database using doctrine. Sometimes it needs to fetch the data for the same entity, the second time however it uses the identity map and therefor might go out of sync with the database (another process can modify the entities in the db). One solution that we tried was to set the query hint `Query::HINT_REFRESH` before we run the DQL query. We however would like to use it also with simple `findBy(..)` calls but that doesn't seem to work? We would also like to be able to set it globally per process so that all the doctrine SELECT queries that are run in that context would actually fetch the entities from the DB. We tried to set the `$em->getConfiguration()->setDefaultQueryHint(Query::HINT_REFRESH, true);` but again that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Couple of possible approaches but what do you want to happen if the database is changed after your query?  The assumption is that you need to do something with this data but it might go stale between the query and whatever you do with it.

Comment: Its ok if the data changed during the actual processing. When I do findBy I expect to get the actual state as stored in the db.

Comment: Is this some sort of long running process?  Not clear why you want changes between queries but it's okay of the data changes after a query.  A simple $entityManager->clear() before each the query might be all you need.

Comment: Yes so its a long running process that is reading from a queue. When a message is inserted to the queue we want to process it using the current state of the DB. Multiple messages might refer to the same entities but between messages the states of the entities might have changed.

Comment: Try $entityManager->clear()  to basically reset the unit of work storage each time a message needs to be processed.  That should clear everything back to ground zero.

Answer (score 0):

[Doctrine explicitly warns you](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html) that it is not meant to be used without a cache.

However if want to ignore this, then Cerad's comment (also mentioned in [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956027/how-to-stop-doctrine-2-from-caching-a-result-in-symfony-2%22this%20answer%22)) sound right. If you want to do it on every query though you might look into hooking into a [doctrine event](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#postload), unfortunately there is no event for `preLoad`, only `postLoad`, but if you really don't care about performance you could create a postLoad listener which first gets the class and id of the loaded entity, calls `clear` on the entity manager and finally reloads it. Sounds very wrong to me though, I wash my hands of it :-)